# rpy2 passing python reserved keyword arguments

Tags: python, r, rpy2, kernel-density

I am trying to use r's density function through python, and I have to pass the 'from', 'to' arguments to the density functions. However, since the word 'from' is a reserved ketyword in python, how can I achieve this?
Thank you. 
Here is the code so far.

```
r_density=robjects.r('density')
f_a = robject.FloatVector(a)
r_a = r_density(f_a, bw='SJ', n=1024) ## Here I need to add 'from' and 'to' arguments
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `dict` [argument-unpacking](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) to pass reserved words as parameter names:

```
r_a = r_density(f_a, bw='SJ', n=1024, **{'from':1, 'to':3})
```

or

```
r_a = r_density(f_a, **{'bw':'SJ', 'n':1024, 'from':1, 'to':3})
```

Comment: This also works for keyword arguments that have a dot in their name in the R function